# Pass values on Page 1 to Page 2 with href and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, href, url-parameters

In this project, a user clicks an email link to a site:

```
example.com/video1?Id=12345&Email=email@email.com
```

I have code on the page to grab the user-specific values for Id and Email...

```
<script>
const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
const Id1 = params.get("Id");
const Email1 = params.get("Email");
</script>
```

What I would like to have happen is the user click a link...

So the values for Id1 and Email1 are passed to the example.com/video2...

I wrote the line...

`<a href="example.com/video2/?Id=Id1&Email=Email1"/a>` And this didn't work...

Then wrote

`<a href="example.com/video2/?Id="+Id1+"&Email="Email1 /a>`

And this didn't work...

Can someone help me understand the correct code to be adding so I can pass the parameters to the next page of the site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try call window.location

like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="RedirectURL();return false;"> My link </a>
<script>
  const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
  const Id1 = params.get("Id");
  const Email1 = params.get("Email");

  function RedirectURL() {
    window.location = createDynamicURL();
  }

  function createDynamicURL() {
    //The variable to be returned
    var URL = "example.com/video1";
    URL += "?id=" + Id1;
    URL += "&Email=" + Email1
    return URL;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="openUrl()">Open</a>
<script>
    //const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    //const Id1 = params.get("Id");
    //const Email1 = params.get("Email");
    const Id1 ="id1234";
    const Email1 = "someone@email.com";

    function openUrl() {
      //window.location="http://example.com/video2/?Id=" + Id1 + "&Email=" + Email1;
      // more readable
      window.location=`http://example.com/video2/?Id=${Id1}&Email=${Email1}`;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

USe `window.open()` if you want to open a new page.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Code:

```
const takeMeThere =()=>window.location.assign(`http://example.com/video2/?Id=${Id1}&Email=${Email1}`);
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="takeMeThere()">Click Here</a>
```

And if you want to open it in a new window, just set `target="_blank"` to `a` tag.

### Solution with jquery:

First set an `id` to that `a` tag, I'm setting it to `"me"`, then this is the code

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
   $("#me").attr("href", `http://example.com/video2/?Id=${Id1}&Email=${Email1}`)
})
```

HTML:

Link jquery to your page

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then use this

```
<a id="me" href="#">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Went with this approach.  Much appreciated!  One question...

The link now passes through the params to next page... BUT if I right-click to open in new tab/window, the current page loads...

Is there a way for that not to happen?

Comment: Yes, you can solve that issue with jquery, I am editing my answer with jquery code

Comment: Thanks for this! Extremely helpful and grateful to have done.

1 more follow up...

So I simplified the problem partially... In reality, there are multiple links on the page to that destination...

id works great but I'm now creating "me1","me2","me3".....

Is there a way to do that id setup but to be used multiple times throughout the page without having to create a unique id each time?

Comment: This way or that way everything can be done what we need, idea is not pre fixed, it generates after hearing the stories. Put a short story of your project here, If I get any idea I'll send you a live chat link to solve it together

Comment: And if the above answer solves your first mentioned issue, also please mark that answer as as a solution (with tick mark where the answer starts)